# Does FutureOr<T> have a reified type of Future<T> / <T>?

Tags: dart

I have a class in AngularDart as followings:

```
abstract class Validator {
  Map validate(AbstractControl c);
}
```

Looking closely, this *used* to be (before we added strong-mode support):

```
abstract class Validator {
  validate(AbstractControl c);
}
```

The issue that it technically supports returning a *Future* or *Map*.

I'd like to refactor this and properly type it using `FutureOr`:

```
abstract class Validator {
  FutureOr<T> validate(AbstractControl c);
}
```

Will I be able to use an `is` check at runtime? (In DDC and dart2js)

```
void runValidator(Validator v) {
  var result = v.validate(...);
  if (result is Future) {
    // async...
  } else {
    // sync...
  }
}
```

Am I thinking about this correctly?

**EDIT**: As mentioned below, I mean

```
if (result is Future<T>) {

} else if (result is T) {

}
```

One more question, would `validate` match these two `typedef`s:

```
Future<Map> AsyncValidate(AbstractControl c);

Map SyncValidate(AbstractControl c);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do `result is Future<Map>`. The actual value returned by the `validate` method is either a `Future` or it's not. The static type of the function doesn't affect that, and since `FutureOr<Map>` isn't an actual class, you can't have an object that is "a FutureOr". It's either a real `Future<Map>` *or* it's a `Map`.

For the second question, that depends on what yo mean by "match".
You can override the method with a method that returns either `Map` or `FutureMap`:

```
abstract class Validator {
  FutureOr<Map> validate(abstractControl c);
}
class AsyncValidator extends Validator { 
  Future<Map> validate(AbstractControl c) {...}   
}
class SyncValidator extends Validator { 
  Map validate(AbstractControl c) {...} 
}
```

That is, you can use one of the function types you mention *as* a `Validator.validate`, but not in the other direction.

```
typedef FutureOr<Map> Validate(AbstractControl c);
typedef Future<Map> AsyncValidate(AbstractControl c);
typedef Map SyncValidate(AbstractControl c);
Validator v = ...;
Validate f0 = v.validate;  // Safe.
AsyncValidate f1 = v.validate; // BAD assignment.
SyncValidate f2 = v.validate; // BAD assignment.

Map syncValidate(AbstractControl c) { ... }
Future<Map> asyncValidate(AbstractControl c) { ... }
v = syncValidate;  // Good assignment.
v = asyncValidate;  // Good assignment.
```

In practice, the concrete `validate` method of the validator `v` will probably be assignable to *one* of `f1` or `f2`, but its static type doesn't say which one, so both are considered bad assignments.

You should only very rarely have a non-abstract method that is declared as returning `FutureOr`. In most cases, it's better to just always return a `Future` or a non-`Future`, and declare the method as such. Then you can always use the function as returning `FutureOr` if you need to, but use the more precise type in cases where you need it.

Comment: Yes, sorry, `FutureOr<Map>` or `FutureOr<T>`